In the IDL program, with> and gt, respectively, the running results are different，why?
In the penultimate eighth line of the following procedure：
FUNCTION plant_growth, n_months, initial_plants, pick_strategy
    N = LONARR(n_months + 1)  
    M = LONARR(n_months + 1)  

    N[0] = initial_plants
    M[0] = 0

    FOR t=0, n_months-1 DO BEGIN
        IF t ge 2 THEN M[t] = N[t-2] + M[t-1] - pick_strategy[t]  
        N[t+1] = N[t] + M[t]  
    ENDFOR
    RETURN, N
END

PRO monte_carlo_simulation, n_months, initial_plants
    
    n_months = 8
    initial_plants = 1000
    n_simulations = 27933 
    seed = 0L
    best_strategy = LONARR(n_months)
    max_final_month_plants = 0

    FOR i=0, n_simulations-1 DO BEGIN
        pick_strategy = LONARR(n_months)
        
        FOR j=0, n_months-1 DO BEGIN
            pick_strategy[j] = FLOOR(RANDOMU(seed)*initial_plants)  
        ENDFOR
        N = plant_growth(n_months, initial_plants, pick_strategy)   
        final_month_plants = N[n_months] 
       
        IF final_month_plants gt max_final_month_plants THEN BEGIN
            best_strategy = pick_strategy
            max_final_month_plants = final_month_plants
        ENDIF
    ENDFOR
    PRINT, '最优策略是：', best_strategy
    PRINT, '最后一月的最大母本数量是：', max_final_month_plants
END

Why after replacing 【gt】 with 【>】, the compilation passes, also have results but the results are different?

seed is set to zero and used so the results should be deterministic. This isn't really an MRE since it is too complicated. I'm not even sure that IDL allows use of ">" in this way. The online manual  implies not.

> is the maximum operator and gt is the "greater than" logical operator. So for example:
IDL> print, 3 > 5    ; 5 is the maximum of 3 and 5
       5
IDL> print, 3 gt 5   ; 3 is not greater than 5, so return false (0)
   0

